# How do I get the crtieria from the queryset based on the iteration of the for loop in django?

Tags: python, django

I am looping through a formset which generates a feedback form for assignments, and I need to add a label to display the criteria of an assignment so the user knows what criteria they are marking. I've got as far as creating a queryset and passing this queryset to the context.

The problem comes with trying to access the correct one within the template. The length of the formset and the length of the criteria result set will always be the same so I want to just access the first element on the first iteration and so on. The problem I'm having is an odd one in that I can access the elements manually like so:

```
{{criteria.0}}
```

but whenever I attempt to do so dynamically:

```
{{criteria.forloop.counter}}
```

or

```
 {% with curr=forloop.counter0 %}
            <td>{{ criteria.curr }}</td>
```

Nothing is outputted at all.

Edit:

I've tried a new method of converting the queryset to a list ( view code updated below) and accessing it but not I get an error about not being able to parse the remainder:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[forloop.counter0]' from 'criteria[forloop.counter0]'
```

View Code ( rendering formset):

```
criteria = Criteria.objects.filter(assignmentID=assignment.id)
criteria_list = list(criteria)

formset = FeedbackFormset(queryset=Feedback.objects.none())
for i, criterion in enumerate(criteria):
    formset.forms[i].fields['criteriaLevelID'].queryset = criterion.criterialevel_set.all()

context = {
    'submission': submission,
    'formset': formset,
    'criteria':criteria_list
}

return render(request, 'markingApp/createFeedback.html', context)
```

Comment: How do you construct the formset? Can you provide the view?

Comment: Just added to question

Comment: `Feedback` = `Criteria`?

Comment: what do you mean sorry? an instance of feedback is giving feedback for criteria in an assignment